# why does Laravel 8.x / Jetstream email verification not work?

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am not able to implement email verification using laravel 8.x and Laravel Jetstream.

As the instructions direct in the Laravel Jetstream documentation, I uncommented the emailVerification feature in config/fortify.php.

```
Features::emailVerification(),
```

I implemented the MustVerifyEmail interface in App/Models/User.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

I verified that both of these changes actually occurred on the server.  I ran php artisan optimize to clear the configuration cache. I verified that Laravel will send an email, by using the lost password functionality, which produced the specified email. I inserted the three routes recommended in the Laravel authentication documentation.

Comment: importing/aliasing a class/interface does not mean you are doing anything with it .... did you add the words `implements MustVerifyEmail` to your class declaration?

Comment: thanks, I added implements MustVerifyEmail to the class declaration, and everything worked just fine

Answer (score 16):

You forgot to add implements MustVerifyEmail

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

Comment: This should be added to the documentation. I had the same issue.

Comment: @Pascut Here are the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#model-preparation) for email verification.

Comment: I got the same with Laravel 9. Feature enabled, implemented MustVerifyEmail but the field email_verified_at is not set.